# How to know which package to shade in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, relocation, shading

When a library is released it's very common for the author to provide the Maven/Gradle dependencies.
If the library needs to be shaded, they would also specify the relevant package for the shade plugin:

```
<relocation>
    <pattern>com.github.stefvanschie.inventoryframework</pattern>                       
    <shadedPattern>${shade.base}.inventoryframework</shadedPattern>
</relocation>
```

But what if they don't? For many dependencies I had to search the github page for the top package, which of course can be wrong.
What should I do at that case?

- If it's not clear from the post, I need to create a stand-alone jar(a plugin for a certain system) that contains my dependencies to obviously avoid `ClassNotFoundException`s at runtime.

Comment: First: `If the library needs to be shaded,` a library does not needed to be shaded or even better don't do it because it prevent some features on the consumer side... And why do you need to search github pages? If you consume a dep it's defining it's dependencies itself ... there no need to do that on your own... ? Maybe you can elaborate more what your exact problem is... ?

Comment: Of course you need to shade the dependency, otherwise you would get ClassNotFoundException all over the place at runtime...

Comment: No. If that's the case the original pom is simply wrong... transitive dependencies are done automaticially... Please show the full pom file of such case...

Comment: Where did you see that I talk about transitive dependencies? I am talking about direct dependencies - that have to be shaded in order to be used.

Comment: A library has dependencies plus it's own code. The dependencies of the library  are from the consumer perspective of the library transitive dependencies. Those should never been shaded. If doing so prevents a consumer to overrule the dependencies etc. (for example using a more recent version of a an other lib).

Comment: If we are talking about an executable jar (which can be executed via `java -jar ...`) you can and have to shade but never for a usual consumtion via classpath...

Comment: @khmarbaise That's not really correct--plugin dependencies should not be arbitrarily overridden by plugin consumers. This keeps the plugin in a known-good state.

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't think you understand what I'm trying to build. I need a stand-alone jar that does its job, nothing else.

Comment: It's not arbitrarily overridden. If someone is doing that you should assume the person knews what  it's doing. The plugin itself is in a good state not related... also all Maven plugins not even shading their dependencies ..

Comment: @David You're saying two different things. A jar that can be run anywhere is just a jar with its dependencies. A **plugin** is a different thing because it runs in the context of an existing application.

Comment: @khmarbaise "Assume the person knows what they're doing"... Nope. The whole point of plugins is to isolate behavior. You cannot isolate behavior if consumers can arbitrarily change code the plugin depends on.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay, the only dependency marked as "provided" is the system's API which runs the plugin - all the rest should be shaded...

Comment: @David For **maximum** reliability, yes. Whether or not the ROI of doing so is worth it depends on context.

Comment: @DaveNewton The consumer can not change the code of the plugin. Only override the deps..(yes I know that can result into failings). If it does not work .. problem of the user. All Maven plugins work like that...... but in case of issues the consumer can override the deps (for example with a newer version does not have vulnerbilities anymore)...

Comment: @DaveNewton What do you mean by ROI? This discussion is now way out of its original intention, I asked a very simple question

Comment: Two things. First shading the dependencies into a single jar ... just use the default configuration for maven-shade-plugin and that's it... an other thing is to relocate packages? The question if this is really necessary? If you have a resulting jar which is used as a kind of plugin... that should not be needed?

Comment: @David Return On Investment

Comment: @khmarbaise If you're comfortable shipping plugins users can break in mysterious or hidden ways, great; knock yourself out. I'm not. There are advantages and disadvantages to allowing arbitrary dependency replacement, hence my comment regarding ROI.

Comment: @David The "very simple question"'s answer is "shade everything", but the "very simple question" ignored transitive dependencies, which are usually where issues arise. Direct dependencies are trivially shaded; transitive dependencies are why these tools exist in the first place, because they're essentially impossible to deal with manually for projects of any size.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, you "usually" don't shade your dependencies. This is why information about this is often not provided, and you are on your own.

There are actually few reasons to shade.

If you build a standalone JAR, and you find a conflict in your transitive dependencies, you first try to fix it without shading:

- you set the version of the dependency in `<dependencyManagement>` to some new version and test if it works.
- you reduce the dependencies of your project by writing some stuff yourself.

Only if this does not work, you start shading.

Note: I am talking about standalone JARs. If your JAR runs as a plugin in the context of a different class loader (together with other, unknown plugins) like in Jenkins, then it might be worthwhile to shade a lot of stuff, and to reduce dependencies to an absolute minimum.